# using jquery tooltip with MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 (C# with razor) and I have added a jquery datepicker to my page which works fine.

I now want to add a tooltip which I have done in the code below.

```
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating, new { title = "Rating" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { id = "ReleaseDate" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
```

With the script as

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#ReleaseDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
    $( document ).tooltip();
});
```

The date picker works fine but nothing happens with the tooltip, any ideas?

Here is the full page code for the view

```
  @model testpage.Models.Game

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Game</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating, new { @title = "Rating" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, "Release Date")
    </div>


       <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { id = "ReleaseDate" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#ReleaseDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
        $( document ).tooltip();
    });


</script>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: what are you seeing when you move the cursor to your control ? you see normal tooltip without jquery style or just nothing?

Comment: I am seeing nothing at all

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that adding a title as part of the HTML attributes won't solve?

Comment: When a user hovers over a text box I want a tooltip to show

Answer (score 2):

After a lucky find on google the tooltip doesn't work with `editorfor` so I changed it to `TextBoxfor` and it worked great